# How to fetch 3 objects having the highest values from a List with Stream API

Tags: java, list, sorting, java-stream

I have a method like this:

```
public String mostExpensiveItems() {
        List<Entry> myList = getList();
        List<Double> expensive = myList.stream()
                .map(Entry::getAmount)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .limit(3)
                .toList();

        return "";
    }
```

This method needs to return the *product IDs* of the `3` most expensive items as a string like this:

```
"item1, item2, item3"
```

I should be able to use only streams and I got stuck here. I should be able to sort the items by value then get the product IDs, but I can't seem to make it work.

*Entry class*

```
public class Entry {

    private String productId;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String state;
    private String category;
    private Double amount;

    public Entry(LocalDate orderDate, String state, String productId, String category, Double sales) {
        this.date = orderDate;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.state = state;
        this.category = category;
        this.amount = sales;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
```

Comment: Where is product ID located?

Comment: See comprehensive article here: https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/sort-list-of-objects-by-field-java, specifically the section of `Option 4: Stream interface sorted()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming product ID is inside Entry, it can be something like this.

```
public String mostExpensiveItems() {
    List<Entry> myList = getList();
    List<String> expensive = myList.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getAmount).reversed())
            .limit(3)
            .map(Entry::getProductID)
            .toList();

    return "";
}
```

NB: I didn't test this out yet, but this should be able to convey the idea.

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.joining(", ")`

Comment: Thanks, @steffen, not able to edit now, currently on a mobile device. Just wrote a quick answer for the OP.

Comment: Allow me to put on my pedant hat... this method returns an empty String regardless of what it does internally.  /wellActually

Answer (score 2):

You don't to sort all the given data for this task. Because **sorting is overkill**, when only need to fetch `3` largest values.

Because sorting the hole data set will cost **O(n log n)** time. Meanwhile, this task can be done in a single pass through the list, maintaining only `3` largest previously encountered values in the sorted order. And time complexity will be very close to a **linear time**.

To implement the partial sorting with streams, you can define a *custom collector* (an object that is responsible for accumulating the data from the stream).

You can create a *custom collector* either inline by using one of the versions of the static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)) or by creating a `class` that implements the `Collector` interface.

These are parameters that you need to provide while defining a custom collector:

- **Supplier** `Supplier<A>` is meant to provide a *mutable container* which store elements of the stream. In this case because we need to perform a *partial sorting*, `PriorityQueue` will be handy for that purpose as a mutable container.
- **Accumulator** BiConsumer<A,T> defines how to add elements into the *container* provided by the *supplier*. For this task, the *accumulator* needs to guarantee that queue will not exceed the given size by rejecting values that are smaller than the lowest value previously added to the queue and by removing the lowest value if the size has reached the limit a new value needs to be added.
- **Combiner** `BinaryOperator<A> combiner()` establishes a rule on how to merge two *containers* obtained while executing stream in parallel. Here combiner rely on the same logic that was described for accumulator.
- **Finisher** `Function<A,R>` is meant to produce the final result by transforming the mutable container. The finisher function in the code below turns the queue into an immutable list.
- **Characteristics** allow to provide additional information, for instance `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` which is used in this case denotes that the order in which partial results of the reduction produced while executing in parallel is not significant, which can improve performance of this collector with parallel streams.

Note that with `Collector.of()` only **supplier**, **accumulator** and **combiner** are mandatory, other parameters are defined if needed.

The method below that generates a collector would be more reusable if we apply *generic type parameter* to it and declare it to expect a *comparator* as a parameter (will be used in the constructor of the `PriorityQueue` and while adding elements to the queue).

*Custom collector:*

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> getMaxN(int size, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    
    return Collector.of(
        () -> new PriorityQueue<>(comparator),
        (Queue<T> queue, T next) -> tryAdd(queue, next, comparator, size),
        (Queue<T> left, Queue<T> right) -> {
            right.forEach(next -> tryAdd(left, next, comparator, size));
            return left;
        },
        (Queue<T> queue) -> queue.stream().toList(),
        Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED);
}

public static <T> void tryAdd(Queue<T> queue, T next, Comparator<T> comparator, int size) {
    if (queue.size() == size && comparator.compare(queue.element(), next) < 0) queue.remove(); // if next value is greater than the smallest element in the queue and max size has been exceeded the smallest element needs to be removed from the queue
    if (queue.size() < size) queue.add(next);
}
```

*Stream:*

```
public static <T> String getMostExpensive(List<T> list, Function<T, String> function,
                                          Comparator<T> comparator, int limit) {
    
    return list.stream()
        .collect(getMaxN(limit, comparator))
        .stream()
        .map(function)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

`main()` - demo with dummy `Entries` that expects only `amount` as a parameter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Entry> entries =
        List.of(new Entry("item1", 2.6), new Entry("item2", 3.5), new Entry("item3", 5.7),
                new Entry("item4", 1.9), new Entry("item5", 3.2), new Entry("item6", 9.5),
                new Entry("item7", 7.2), new Entry("item8", 8.1), new Entry("item9", 7.9));

    System.out.println(getMostExpensive(entries, Entry::getProductId,
                                        Comparator.comparingDouble(Entry::getAmount), 3));
}
```

**Output**

```
[item9, item6, item8] // final result is not sorted PriorityQueue maintains the elements in unsorted order (sorting happens only while dequeue operation happens), if these values are requeted to be sorted it could be done by changing the finisher function
```

Comment: This solution is much faster than the other.

Comment: @steffen You should have told that you've spotted `parallel()` method in the pipeline. I forget to remove it after I tested that `combiner` does what it should. My intention was to suggest introducing a partial sorting. The collector above is non-concurrent (as intended), and I didn't understand why you were asking about parallel execution, sorry for that. To make it to be concurrent, it has to declare `Characteristics.CONCURRENT` in the set of characteristics. With that, only instance of the container will get created (as you've mentioned) and the container should be `PriorityBlockingQueue`.