# Create a SortedMap from a List objects with the Value represented as a list of N lowest object's attributes mapped to a particular Key

Tags: java, list, java-stream, comparator, collectors

I am working with a CSV file which includes some information about accidents.

I've created the `Accident` type:

```java
private Integer driverAge;
private Integer vehicleAge;

public Accident(Integer driverAge, Integer vehicleAge) {
    this.driverAge = driverAge;
    this.vehicleAge = vehicleAge;
}
```

I've also created a function that reads all the CSV file, converts all the accidents to a `List<Accident>` and saves it to this type `AccidentArchive`:

```java
private List<Accident> accidents;

public AccidentArchive(List<Accident> accidents) {
    this.accidents = accidents;
}
```

So, we are working with streams which I don't understand entirely yet, and I've been stuck in this exercise where I have to make a function that returns a `SortedMap<K, V>` in which the *key* has to be the `driverAge` values and the value has to be a *list* sorted in ***descending order*** of the `n` lowest `vehicleAge` *values* with the same `driverAge` value:

```java
public SortedMap<Integer, List<Integer>> getNMinVehicleAgesPerDriverAge(Integer n) {
    return getAccidents().stream().
...
```

I have tried using `Collectors.toMap()` and `Collectors.toList()` to somehow make it work, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simplified approach

This problem correlates with the algorithmic question of finding `N` maximum (or minimum) values via partial sorting. It's implementation using collectors might seem tough, therefore I've decided to introduce a simplified solution.

We can use a flavor of [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) that expects *three arguments*:

- a `classifier` *function*,
- a *supplier* `mapFactory` (which allows to specify the resulting type of map)
- and a *downstream collector*.

As a downstream collector of `groupingBy()` we can utilize `collectingAndThen` with a combination of collectors `mapping()` and `toList()` and a *function* that will sort the whole resulting list mapped to each *key*, and then will drop unnecessary values retaining only `n` lowest `vehicleAge`:

```
public SortedMap<Integer, List<Integer>> getNMinVehicleAgesPerDriverAge(Integer n) {
    return getAccidents().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Accident::getDriverAge,
            TreeMap::new,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.mapping(Accident::getVehicleAge, Collectors.toList()),
                list -> list.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                    .limit(n)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))));
}
```

#### More performant version

As I've said before, we don't need to sort all values mapped to each *key* when we need only some of them. When `n` is dwarfish in comparison to the total size of the list (like `3` to `100,000` for every key) it will cause a serious performance hit.

We can introduce a partial sorting by using `PriorityQueue` (which is an implementation of the Heap data structure built-in in the JDK).

To enhance the previous solution, we need to replace the downstream collector of `groupingBy()` you can utilize a combination of `mapping()` and a **custom collector** backed by the `PriorityQueue` which retain only `n` lowest `vehicleAge` values associated with each `driverAge`:

```
public SortedMap<Integer, List<Integer>> getNMinVehicleAgesPerDriverAge(Integer n) {
    return getAccidents().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Accident::getDriverAge,
            TreeMap::new,
            Collectors.mapping(Accident::getVehicleAge, 
                getMaxN(n, Comparator.<Integer>reverseOrder()))));
}
```

The method provided below is responsible for generating a *custom collector* based on the provided maximum size of the resulting list and a *comparator*. The logic behind it was explained in great detail in [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72064317/17949945):

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> getMaxN(int size, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        
    return Collector.of(
        () -> new PriorityQueue<>(comparator),
        (Queue<T> queue, T next) -> tryAdd(queue, next, comparator, size),
        (Queue<T> left, Queue<T> right) -> {
            right.forEach(next -> tryAdd(left, next, comparator, size));
            return left;
        },
        (Queue<T> queue) -> queue.stream().toList(),
        Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED);
}
    
public static <T> void tryAdd(Queue<T> queue, T next, Comparator<T> comparator, int size) {
    if (queue.size() == size && comparator.compare(next, queue.element()) < 0) queue.remove(); // if next value is less than the smallest element in the queue and max size has been exceeded the largest element needs to be removed from the queue
    if (queue.size() < size) queue.add(next);
}
```

By the way, if your assignment doesn't specify the requirement to utilize `SortedMap` as a return type. It better to use `NavigableMap` interface, which defines a wider range of methods, instead.

Comment: Ohhh It works!! It has gotten a little more complicated than I thought though

Comment: @GabrielCorrales Well, I'm editing the answer right now, in a couple of minutes I'll add a more simple (although less performant) version, which sorts all data set mapped to a particular *key* and then drops unnecessary values instead of partial sorting via `PriorityQueue` .

Comment: @GabrielCorrales Updated the answer with a simplified solution, it should produce the same result. Try it out.